# Yii Select Using Custom Field

Tags: php, mysql, yii

Im trying to use a custom field to create another custom field, but Im getting error.
I created that sample code to be easier to understand.

Model.php:

```
public custom1;
public custom2;
```

Example Code:

```
...
$criteria->select=array("'custom1' AS custom1, CONCAT('variable: ', custom1) AS custom2");
...
```

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'custom1' in 'field list'.
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the `select` to a string not an array?

Comment: @topher I need to use it as an `array` because Im using CONCAT, and yii only allow if its an array because have commas =/

Comment: Try `$criteria->select=array("\`custom1\` AS custom1, CONCAT('variable: ', custom1) AS custom2");`

Comment: @topher the problem is when using `custom1` to create te `custom2` field, because `custom1` not recognized as a field.

Comment: Do you have in table column `column1` ? Please show create table sql code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, because you use function in select it have to use with CDbExpression:

```
$criteria->select = array(
  new CDbExpression('custom as custom1'),
  new CDbExpression('CONCAT("variable: ", custom) AS custom2'),
);
```